# 100 pieces 1 opportunity, choose wisely!

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, probability, monty-hall

Say you have a cake that is cut into 100 pieces.

One of the pieces has a hidden prize.

100 people take turns, each taking a piece in sequence hoping to find the prize.

**Note:** I slightly modified *(see italics)* the question below to provide greater clarity; I hope that is allowed. If not I will revert it.

**Q: Which turn (C) yields the (highest probability/*optimal risk*) of finding the prize? 
*factoring in failed attempts from previous players***

Please express your solution in a formula and provide an explanation behind your reasoning.

**For example**:

1st person has 
C1 = 1/100 chances of finding the prize.

IF the first person does not find it, then the 2nd person has (and correct me if I'm wrong)

C2 = 1/99 - (chance of the first person did not find it)

*^ C2 chooses 1 out of the remaining 99 pieces of cake ^*

...

If the first 98 people did not find the prize then the 99th person has:

C99 = 1/2 - (cumulative chance the first 98 people did not find it)

**To sum up:**

The 1st person has the highest chance of not having someone else finding the prize, but the largest pool to choose from.

VS

the 100th person has the smallest pool to choose from however takes the largest risk of someone finding the prize before them.

Note: I do not know the answer to this question. I am interested in your logical approach.

Thank you and have fun!

Food for thought: [The Monty Hall problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem)

**Edit**:

what would happen if you took into consideration the knowledge that the previous people did not find the prize?

*Can we predict a turn that will yield a high reward vs efficient risk, given the knowledge that the people before you had not found the prize. 
The more people that fail to find the winning piece, the higher the chance that the next person will find it, however, let too many people take a piece before you and chances are you will lose because someone else will find it.*

Comment: If your C2 has a subtraction, it is certainly incorrect since the chance that the first person *didn't find* the piece is significantly greater than 1/99, making C2 less than 0. An "and" typically indicates multiplication in probabilities.

Comment: I agree with Ian. Could you recheck that part again, please :)

Comment: Related:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96331/in-russian-roulette-is-it-best-to-go-first/96409#96409

Comment: At the risk of getting pedantic, you haven't specified that the chance of the prize being in any piece is equal. One piece, for example, might be twice the size of the others.

Comment: Monty Hall doesn't really come into play here.  Monty Hall was interesting because the door to reveal was not chosen at random; it was specifically chosen not to reveal the prize.  The cake here will be selected at random.

Comment: Not all pieces are created equal. This turns out to be not very random in practice. Source: observing the game being played over and over again.

Comment: This is not a puzzle but a statistics question.

Comment: Christian, I mention Monty Hall because I would like to take into consideration the most effective turn to choose a piece, thus reducing randomness, based on previous peoples failed (revealed) choices. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @TheCakeisaLie...It makes sense.  It's just that the order matter in the Monty Hall problem precisely because the revealed door is not random.  If you change the monty hall problem such that the host can reveal the price, and then look at only those cases where the host does not reveal a price it does not matter if you change your choice or not.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

What you're missing here is the chance of playing at all, given that the game ends when someone finds the prize. (or, chance of finding a prize goes to 0, which is the same thing)

```
Person 1 has a 100/100 chance of playing, and a 1/100 chance of winning.
Person 2 has a 99/100 chance of playing, and a 1/99 chance of winning.
Person 3 has a 98/100 chance of playing and a 1/98 chance of winning.
...
Person 100 has a 1/100 chance of playing and a 100/100 chance of winning.
(Fractions left unreduced for clarity)
```

When you multiply these out, you get 1/100 chance of playing AND winning.

In other words, playing sequentially doesn't change the odds from playing simultaneously.

Comment: While your reply was 12 seconds later than athin's, it better explains why everyone has the same chance.

Comment: While I accept your answer for the insight provided, allow me to extend my question to: what would happen if you took into consideration the knowledge that the previous people did not find the prize? Can we predict a turn that will wield a high reward vs efficient risk, or is the knowledge of previous losers negligible since every choice is predefined with equal chances since before 1st turn?

Comment: @TheCakeisaLie... this wouldn't change the math in any way. The only thing that would increase your odds if you know X amount of people didn't find the reward and you are offered to switch your piece.

Comment: The answer still holds. Assume 3 people failed already.  Starting the puzzle over again gives a similar solution, 97/97 * 1/97,  96/97 * 2/96 ...

Comment: @IliaL but that is exactly my question( clarified in Edit ) Since I can choose X amount of people, that means I am offered to switch every time I let someone take another piece before me. 

ChrisCudmore does it though? since 
(100/100)*(1/100) not equal to (97/97)*(1/97) etc...

Comment: @TheCakeisaLie... The increase in chance is also increase the chance that another person could have taken the winning piece, so the chances remain the same.

Comment: You need to factor in the 3% chance that one of those first three won already,   -- As for switching, that's a whole new puzzle, which should be asked separately (i.e. new question).

Comment: +1, but please do not misuse code formatting for non-code text. This causes accessibility problems, because you can mislead alternative browsing technology (e.g. screen readers for the blind) into thinking your text *is* code, which may make it more difficult to understand (e.g. reading letter-by-letter is not unheard of). Please use a quote box, a bulleted list, or whatever else you like, but not a code box. Thank you.

Comment: Whoa hold on there, @TheCakeisaLie...  You seem to be confused about Monty Hall and trying to apply it where it doesn't belong.  A Monty Hall example would occur if an informed party gives you more information by showing you a piece that he already knew was empty. As there is no interesting selection mechanism to give you hints, Finding out the that first piece of cake is empty does not give any additional information about the probability distribution between the other pieces of cake.

Answer (score 37):

Actually,

> They are same.
>
>  First person: $1/100$.
>  Second person: $99/100 \times 1/99 = 1/100$.
>  Third person: $99/100 \times 98/99 \times 1/98 = 1/100$.
>  ...
>  Last person: $99/100 \times 98/99 \times 97/98 \times ... \times 1/1 = 1/100$

Comment: Sniped!  I type too slow

Comment: Welp sorry, I also tried to type this quickly on my mobile and hoping noone sniped it ><

Answer (score 22):

Other people have already given correct answers, but I wanted to suggest a different way of thinking about the question that involves less calculation:

> First of all, let the people pick their pieces of cake but not check them for prizes. One of those hundred pieces of cake contains the prize. It's equally likely to be any one of them. (Assuming that there's no visible clue to which one contains the prize, which of course would complicate things.) Therefore, the winner is equally likely to be any of the hundred people. It makes no difference in what order they check their pieces of cake: all that matters is which person's piece has the prize.

Answer (score 6):

Since

> no one knows anything about the piece of cake they pick, it's a random choice. The problem then becomes this: Randomly distribute 100 pieces of cake to 100 individuals - who is most likely to have the special piece?

It should be clear that

> everybody has the same chance of having the special piece. It doesn't matter if everyone chooses their piece and checks it sequentially, or if everyone gets their piece and checks simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer your edited question. In case that you have prior knowledge that the ones before you didn't find the price then the better turn is...the last.
 It's a little underwhelming but basically you have a 1*100/n% chance in getting the price with any number left of cake pieces (being "n" the number of pieces) so 100/1 is 100%.

Comment: Well the last piece has 100% chance yes, If you manage to get there, however I do not accept it as an answer since the accumulative chance of the prize being found before that is much higher, at least to my understanding..

Comment: @TheCakeisaLie... Strictly speaking, if none of previous 99 participants got the prize, you are sure to get it as a hundreth one. That makes probability equal 1. However, the probability to get there is 1/100, so the overall probabillity to win as the last to take your piece is ...1/100, same as for every one.

Answer (score 1):

> Put a number from 1 through 100 under each piece of cake (suppose the number 1 is the one with the prize). The order of choosing pieces generates a sequence of numbers. There are 100! possible outcomes (permutations of the 100-term sequence), and each number appears exactly the same number of times at any chosen position. Hence the probability of hitting the number 1 is the same, whichever position you take in a row of consumers.